# Include rewrite file in vhost configuration

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache

Can someone tell me if it is possible to include a file in your vhost configuration which contains all your rewrite rules?

Because of the 500+ rewrite rules that have to be applied, I would prefer if they were in a different file so that the vhost configuration would still be readable.

The amount of rewrites are necessary because they contain old to new shop articles.

Answer (score 4):

Apache allows the `Include` directive:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include

In fact, any non-trivial Web server configuration would have some form of `Include` structure and most Linux distros have it as part of the package.

If you have so many rewrite rules, you might want to organise them up and have the wildcard functionality of `Include` to bring all the files into the configuration.